# Call object property with variable

Tags: javascript

This code doesn't work quite as i want to.

```
var csd = {large10x10: 0}
var nextitem = "large10x10";
buildings.push(nextitem,"black",a);
csd.nextitem += 1;
```

at `csd.nextitem +=1` I want it to add 1 to csd.large10x10. How do I do that? Or what do I google to find the answer?

Thanks

Comment: Try `csd[nextitem] += 1` (or even `++csd[nextitem]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the property whose value is in `nextitem` not the one named nextitem.
In JavaScript, this is done with bracket notation.

Try

```
csd[nextitem] += 1;
```

Here is a [fiddle with the code working](http://jsfiddle.net/gvPUf/)